# Why is always the first changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I can update a Note but if I update it it updates the first note which is in myPosts section.

I really don´t understand. If I click on a Note which I create then it goes to the site "/notesEdit" so and I can see there the current forumName and forumDescription but if I change it, it doesn´t change the current selected note instead the first in List.

Here are the Notes which the user sees which he has created :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MainScreen from "../components/MainScreen";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { deleteNoteAction, listForumUser } from "../../redux/forum/noteActions";

function NotesMe({ history, search }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;

  const noteList = useSelector((state) => state.noteList);
  const { notes } = noteList;
  console.log(noteList);

  const deleteHandler = (_id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      dispatch(deleteNoteAction(_id));
      dispatch(listForumUser());
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listForumUser());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <MainScreen title={` ${userInfo.userName}´s Forum..`}>
      <Link to="createForum">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          Create New Forum
        </Button>
      </Link>

      {notes &&
        notes.map((forum) => (
          <Accordion key={forum._id} defaultActiveKey="0">
            <Accordion.Item style={{ margin: 10 }} key={forum._id}>
              <Accordion.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <span
                  style={{
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    flex: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }}
                >
                  {forum.forumName}
                </span>

                <div>
                  <Link
                    to={{
                      pathname: "/notesEdit",
                      query: { forum },
                    }}
                  >
                    <Button id="EditButton">Edit</Button>
                  </Link>

                  <Button
                    variant="danger"
                    className="mx-2"
                    onClick={() => deleteHandler(forum._id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </Accordion.Header>

              <Accordion.Body>
                <blockquote className="blockquote mb-0">
                  <ReactMarkdown>{forum.forumDescription}</ReactMarkdown>
                  <footer className="blockquote-footer">
                    Created on{" "}
                    <cite title="Source Title">
                      {/* {forum.published_on && forum.published_on.substring(0, 300)} */}
                      {/* {forum.user.userName && forum.user.userName} */}
                    </cite>
                  </footer>
                </blockquote>
              </Accordion.Body>
            </Accordion.Item>
          </Accordion>
        ))}
    </MainScreen>
  );
}

export default NotesMe;
```

and this is the site where the user can change it :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import MainScreen from "../components/MainScreen";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { updateNoteAction } from "../../redux/forum/noteActions";
import "./NotesEdit.css";

const NotesEdit = ({ history }) => {
  const [forumName, setforumName] = useState("");
  const [forumDescription, setforumDescription] = useState("");
  const { query } = useLocation();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const { userInfo } = userLogin;
  const noteList = useSelector((state) => state.noteList);
  const { notes } = noteList;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      setforumName(query.forum.forumName);
      setforumDescription(query.forum.forumDescription);
    }
  }, [query]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(updateNoteAction({ forumName, forumDescription }));
  };

  return (
    <MainScreen title="EDIT MyNote">
      <div id="ForumEdit">
        <Row className="ForumContainer">
          <Col md={6}>
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
              <Form.Group controlId="forumName">
                <Form.Label>forumName</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  id="forumNameInput"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter forumName"
                  value={forumName}
                  onChange={(e) => setforumName(e.target.value)}
                ></Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Group controlId="forumDescription">
                <Form.Label>forumDescription</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  id="forumDescriptionInput"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter forumDescription"
                  value={forumDescription}
                  onChange={(e) => setforumDescription(e.target.value)}
                ></Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>
              <Button
                id="EditButton"
                type="submit"
                varient="primary"
                onClick={submitHandler}
              >
                Update
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Col>
          <Col
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          ></Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </MainScreen>
  );
};

export default NotesEdit;
```

```
export const updateNoteAction = (forum) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: NOTES_UPDATE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/forum/";

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.put(url, forum, config);

    dispatch({
      type: NOTES_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message;
    dispatch({
      type: NOTES_UPDATE_FAIL,
      payload: message,
    });
  }
};
```

```
const forumSchema = ({
    forumName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    forumDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    user: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        
        ref: 'user',
        
    },
    published_on: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("LLL")
    },
});
```

Comment: I've not used redux but why does the delete take an id but edit doesn't? `dispatch(updateNoteAction({ forumName, forumDescription }));`

Comment: If it doesn't need one because of redux magic, maybe tag this with redux and put your reducer code in here?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I add some more details

Comment: I added the redux tag as this seems very related to that. I don't know what magic would make it know which forum to update. There's no ID in the url or anything.  =)

Comment: So what I have to do? @Nikki9696

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that you're not sending the request to your API correctly. How does the API know which forum to update with the data provided? If you don't pass the ID, does it always update the first note?